# passing php variable to javascript syntax issue

Tags: php, javascript

trying to upload pictures to a users folder /uploads/$uid i think i have the variable syntax right maybe the syntax in file path is incorrect /uploads/user/

```
(function($){
   $.simpleuploader = {version: '0.1'};
  $.fn.simpleuploader = function(options){
    // the container to inject the form into
    var $this = $(this);

    var user = '<?php echo $uid; ?>'; //is users id from session

    // set defults
    var defaults = {
        prefix: 'simpleuploader-',
        latency: 500,
        reuse: true,
        when: 'onchange',
        submitText: 'Submit',
        disabledOpacity: .3,
        settings: {
            fullPath: 'http://www.mysite.com/image_upload/uploads/user/',
            relPath: '../uploads/user/',

        },
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What is not working? Are you getting any error messages? If so, what do they say?

Comment: Are the permissions set properly on your uploads directory?

Comment: the image doesn't load in folder permisions 707

Comment: Remove the comma at the end of `settings.relPath` .

Also, I would use `var user = <?php echo json_encode($uid); ?>; //is users id from session` instead, just in case `$uid` contains some complex symbols.

Answer (score 0):

Were you trying to use the user variable when defining the paths?
You should did it this way

```
var defaults = {
    prefix: 'simpleuploader-',
    latency: 500,
    reuse: true,
    when: 'onchange',
    submitText: 'Submit',
    disabledOpacity: .3,
    settings: {
        fullPath: 'http://www.mysite.com/image_upload/uploads/' + user + '/',
        relPath: '../uploads/' + user + '/',

    }
```

Comment: for some reason its not processing-- var user = '<?php echo json_encode($uid); ?>'; when i view the results-- fullPath: 'http://www.mysite.com/image_upload/uploads/<?php echo json_encode($uid); ?>';/