# java script not processing php variable

Tags: php, javascript

for some reason its not processing-- var user = variable, when i view the results--  mysite.com/image_upload/uploads/';/

```
  (function($){
     $.simpleuploader = {version: '0.1'};
     $.fn.simpleuploader = function(options){
    // the container to inject the form into
    var $this = $(this);


    var user = '<?php echo json_encode($uid); ?>';

    // set defults
    var defaults = {
        prefix: 'simpleuploader-',
        latency: 500,
        reuse: true,
        when: 'onchange',
        submitText: 'Submit',
        disabledOpacity: .3,
        settings: {
            fullPath: 'http://www.mysite.com/image_upload/uploads/' + user + '/',
            relPath: '../uploads/' + user + '/',
            maxSize: '4194304',
            maxW: 300,
            maxH: 300,
            colorR: 255,
            colorG: 255,
            colorB: 255
        },
```

Comment: What actually gets emitted to the browser as JavaScript?

Comment: Try to quote php echo into double quotes.

Comment: Please post the output of `<?php var_dump($uid); ?>`

Comment: possible duplicate of [passing php variable to javascript syntax issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9591253/passing-php-variable-to-javascript-syntax-issue)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't actually want to use `json_encode` here...

Comment: This code is inside a php page? If yes have you declared it on top of your page?

Comment: You asked the same question less than an hour ago. This one should be closed.

Answer (score 0):

`json_encode()` produces a javascript object, and that does not belong inside quotes.  There is probably a quote or something in your `echo` statement that is messing up the javascript.  Try changing that line to this.

```
var user = <?php echo json_encode($uid); ?>;
```

That being said, `json_encode()` on a single variable is bad practice, and a weird way to do something.  If the $uid is just a number, why not use:

```
var user = <?php echo $uid; ?>;
```